# When an action is not carried out, who is the subject?

Tags: parts-of-speech, subjects

“My mother gave me money.”

My mother is the subject, money is the direct object, and I am the indirect object who receives the money.

“My mother did not give me money.”

This sentence states what my mother did not do. Because she did not act, there was no direct object for me to receive. Is my mother’s inaction the topic of the speaker (me)?

I’m not an English buff (just letting that be known). Thanks.

EDIT: Thank you all for clarification. I am definitely blending philosophy with features of language and I think what I’m getting at is better suited for the philosophy site.

Comment: Yes, it is the subject. "My mother" is the person about whom the action refers, it tells us what she did not do. To call a verb an "action word" is a bit misleading, it is a rough summary of what it means but there are many cases where no actual action took place.

Comment: You are being too literal when you say "Because she did not act, there was no direct object for me to receive." True, but the object *of the sentence* is money. "Gave me" is understood to mean gave **to** me, known as the indirect object.

Comment: Subjects and direct objects are features of language, not of the things language describes. "Mother" is the subject of the sentence because the sentence is essentially *about* her; she is its subject. Similarly, "money" is the direct object of "give" because "money" is the thing which "give" could, would, or should give; it is the object of "give", directly. It makes no difference at all to a grammarian that a random adverb appears somewhere in there. ("Not" is an adverb.)

Comment: Suppose she gave you money and took it back..., the situation is not dissimilar, right?  Can it then be that she didn't give and hence who could be the object?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the *effect* of the sentence with the *meaning* of the sentence. No matter whether an action takes place or not, how the parts of speech function in the sentence do not change. In this case, "My mother did not give me the money," the direct object is still **money** and the indirect object is still **me**.

Comment: nice explanation. It would be better with sources, but the question is so basic that your answer explains it enough. BTW..the Q is well on its way  to VTC. If yu get a DV it is not mine, but no +1.